# Exchange 2007 - export emails from user mailbox to root folder of archive mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, export

I am new to Exchange Server 2007 management, and am attempting to move emails from a specific time range from employee mailboxes to a the inbox of a dedicated mailbox on the same exchange server.  I am able to move the emails into the target mailbox with the following script in Exchange Management Shell:

```
Get-Mailbox -identity employee1 -ResultSize Unlimited | Export-Mailbox -StartDate "11/05/2012" -EndDate "11/06/2012" -TargetMailbox archivemailbox@companyname.com -TargetFolder <folder>
```

But, this imports employee1's emails AND their entire subfolder structure into a new folder in archivemailbox.

Are there any modifications/additions I can make to the script in order to move ALL emails in employee1's mailbox (regardless of whether or not they reside within a subfolder) into the root Inbox folder in archivemailbox?

Alternatively, is there a way (scripts, third-party tools, etc.) to traverse all of the folders within a mailbox and move all emails to the root Inbox folder?

Thanks in advance!